# Using CASE instead of using UNION in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like this shown below

```
  SELECT A.BUSINESS_UNIT
,A.ASSET_ID
,A.BOOK
,A.FISCAL_YEAR
,A.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD
,A.CATEGORY
,A.ACCOUNT_FA AS ACCOUNT
,A.CURRENCY_CD
,'COST_ADD' AS MOT
,A.COST_ADD AS AMOUNT
FROM SYSADM.PS_DEPR_RPT A
WHERE A.BOOK IN ('CORP-BASE','CORPORATE')
AND NOT (A.COST_ADD=0)
  UNION
SELECT A1.BUSINESS_UNIT
,A1.ASSET_ID
,A1.BOOK
,A1.FISCAL_YEAR
,A1.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD
,A1.CATEGORY
,A1.ACCOUNT_AD AS ACCOUNT
,A1.CURRENCY_CD
,'ACCUM_DEPR_ADD' AS MOT
,A1.ACCUM_DEPR_ADD AS AMOUNT
FROM SYSADM.PS_DEPR_RPT A1
WHERE A1.BOOK IN ('CORP-BASE','CORPORATE')
AND NOT (A1.ACCUM_DEPR_ADD=0);
```

I want to remove the UNION which I have used in this to increase the performance of the query. As it is taking around 120sec to run the query, I want to make it more efficient. I used CASE for this. Query run time is less(4sec) but, i have a data mismatch here. Please help me on this.

PS: Query that I prepared using CASE is given below. Kindly suggest if any corrections required.

```
 select BUSINESS_UNIT
,ASSET_ID
,BOOK
,FISCAL_YEAR
,ACCOUNTING_PERIOD
,CATEGORY
,ACCOUNT
,MOT
,AMOUNT
FROM
(SELECT A.BUSINESS_UNIT
,A.ASSET_ID
,A.BOOK
,A.FISCAL_YEAR
,A.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD
,A.CATEGORY
,A.ACCOUNT_FA AS ACCOUNT
,A.CURRENCY_CD,
case when NOT (A.COST_ADD=0) then 'COST_ADD'
    when NOT (A.ACCUM_DEPR_ADD=0) then 'ACCUM_DEPR_ADD' 
    else 'x'
    END
    as MOT,
case when NOT (A.COST_ADD=0) then A.COST_ADD 
    when NOT (A.ACCUM_DEPR_ADD=0) then A.ACCUM_DEPR_ADD 
    else 0
    END
    as AMOUNT
  FROM SYSADM.PS_DEPR_RPT A
WHERE A.BOOK IN ('CORP-BASE','CORPORATE')) X
where mot <> 'x' and amount <> 0;
```

Comment: please update question to be more specific on the issue. does your solution work? what is wrong with it? be precise and include sample outputs.

Comment: Is it possible to have rows where `a.cost_add <> 0` and `a.accum_depr_add <> 0`? If so, do you want to count them as `COST_ADD` or as `ACCUM_DEPR_ADD`?

Comment: Are you sure you really wanted `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`? Can there be duplicates in one of the queries that need be removed?

Comment: And please answer William's question. If it is possible for a record to have `cost_add <> 0` and `accum_depr_add <> 0`, which seems likely, then you cannot replace `UNION` with a mere `WHERE` clause and still get the same result.

Comment: @william Hi William thanks for your reply. But the scenario here is not for only two cases. It includes 10-12 cases which I didn't mentioned here due to space constraints. I have already tried your method of giving AND in between I am getting the data mismatch where I see <> 0 values in a single row.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner , Thanks for your reply. I tried using UNION ALL instead of UNION. Here I get duplicate values. Though I have used the distinct in the query where I have used UNION ALL, it is taking the more time than usual to present the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
SELECT 
 A.BUSINESS_UNIT
,A.ASSET_ID
,A.BOOK
,A.FISCAL_YEAR
,A.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD
,A.CATEGORY
,A.ACCOUNT_FA AS ACCOUNT
,A.CURRENCY_CD
,CASE WHEN A.COST_ADD <> 0 THEN 'COST_ADD' ELSE 'ACCUM_DEPR_ADD' END AS MOT
,CASE WHEN A.COST_ADD <> 0 THEN A.COST_ADD ELSE A.ACCUM_DEPR_ADD END AS AMOUNT
FROM SYSADM.PS_DEPR_RPT A
WHERE A.BOOK IN ('CORP-BASE','CORPORATE');
```

Comment: The only issue I could see is that the two where clauses in the original example are not necessarily mutually exclusive, so you may want to have additional checks in your case and where clauses.

Comment: Oh, and there may be records filtered out that are not wanted in case both where conditions are false. To match the original results, I’d add an AND ( A.COST <> 0 OR A.ACCUM_DEPR_ADD <> 0 )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
A.BUSINESS_UNIT
,A.ASSET_ID
,A.BOOK
,A.FISCAL_YEAR
,A.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD
,A.CATEGORY
,A.ACCOUNT_FA AS ACCOUNT
,A.CURRENCY_CD
,CASE WHEN A.COST_ADD <> 0 THEN 'COST_ADD' ELSE 'ACCUM_DEPR_ADD' END AS MOT
,CASE WHEN A.COST_ADD <> 0 THEN A.COST_ADD ELSE A.ACCUM_DEPR_ADD END AS AMOUNT
FROM SYSADM.PS_DEPR_RPT A
WHERE A.BOOK IN ('CORP-BASE','CORPORATE')
and (A.COST_ADD <> 0 or A.ACCUM_DEPR_ADD <> 0);
```